# Detecting refresh/postback conditions working in debug but not production

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, page-refresh

After searching the web, there seems to be a strong consensus that a good way to prevent a refresh from triggering a database access is to use a ViewState variable and Session variable to detect the condition.  Here's the code in my base page class:

```
    protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnLoad( e ); 

        if ( IsPostBack && ViewState["REFRESH_CHECK"] != Session["REFRESH_CHECK"] )
        {
            IsRefresh = true;
        }
        Session["REFRESH_CHECK"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        ViewState["REFRESH_CHECK"] = Session["REFRESH_CHECK"];
    }

    public virtual bool IsRefresh
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

So in my pages I have some code that looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( !IsPostBack )
        {
            if ( !IsRefresh )
            {
                doStuffThatShouldOnlyBeDoneOnce();
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly while debugging, however when I run on a production system, I always get two invocations of the doStuff...() method.  Of course when I debug it, there is only one call ever.

It may or may not be relevant, but I am using nested Master pages too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Too risky code, for many reasons can not work, session lost, open the same page two times, twice postback in short time....

Answer (score 2):

Oh man please do not use this code, this can break your web page. For a simple test, try to open same page with two different tabs and you will see that the solution has failed. 
The only solution for the F5 refresh problem is `Response.Redirect`. 
I have tried this soltion so I am telling you from my experience.

Comment: Ok so I replaced the old code with your suggestion and I'm still getting the same problem.  I do have some other information that may help.  I'm capturing the stack trace on every Page_Load() invocation.  On the first page displayed, everything works as expected and the way it was before.

On subsequent pages, there are three calls to Page_Load, one of which IsValidPost is false, and two which are true.  And of course I'm seeing two database accesses.

Comment: Are you using GridView inside Update Panel?

Comment: try Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl,false)

Comment: Well that got rid of the extra Page_Load() where IsValidPost is false, so instead of three, I'm getting two and still have the same issue.

Comment: which .NET version you are using? I remember in .NET 3.5 gridview had this problem with RowCommand event.

Comment: So this is interesting - When its calling Page_Load() twice, its calling it once from the page I'm already on and shows that it is neither a postback and its valid, and then it calls from the page I'm going to, also neither as a postback and as valid.  The only code being called with the button press is `Response.Redirect("pagename", false);`

Answer (score 0):

Half-answer

I was unable to figure out why Page_Load() is getting invoked twice in a production environment and only once in debug mode.

None of the techniques regarding refresh hitting the DB twice were working for me either.

So the approach I took was to change where the work was being done.  Instead of executing the code when a new page was being loaded, I executed the code in a delegate for the button control when it was pressed prior to the redirect.

```
delegate( Object o, EventArgs eventArgs ) 
{
    doStuffHere();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect( "admin/Admin.aspx", false );
}
```

In this case, the next page needs some setup done based on the previous page, so long as I precede all redirects with this, everything is ok.  This does not work if a user goes straight to a URL, but for this particular situation thats ok - the page won't be fully populated, but it won't cause an error and the user can still do work.